# Email Autoresponder to trigger when a new row added to tab in Google Sheets, following Google Form Submissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to send different emails, depending on the form responses.  I am very capable in Google Sheets and was hoping to do most of the data handling there while only relying on App Script to send the actual email.

To do this, I hope to pull the email_recipient, reply_to email address, email_subject and email_body directly from cells in the Sheet.

When I try to to run the script, I get the following error:

> Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient
> sendConfirmationEmail  @ Code.gs:12

Here is the script that I am working with:

```
function sendConfirmationEmail() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET-ID')
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UPDATED')
const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
    
const email_recipient = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 34).getValue();
const reply_to = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 35).getValue();
const email_subject = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 36).getValue();
const email_body = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 37).getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail(email_recipient,reply_to,email_subject,email_body)
```

}

**Any ideas what I am missing?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with no problem, which tells me the issue is probably not in your code. Three things that occur to me to check:

- That you have the correct sheet ID (to troubleshoot, maybe try this with *getActiveSpreadsheet* instead of *openById*)
- That the sheet in question is, indeed, called 'UPDATED'
- That your column values are correct

To troubleshoot the last, I'd comment out the *MailApp* line and throw a *toast* or *ui.alert* in there, display the value of your four email variables, and see what you get. You could be off by a column (maybe the email address is in column 33 or 35 instead of 34?)... or something else along those lines.